$\liminf$ and $\limsup$ for partial sums of the Ehrenfeucht-Mycielski sequence
Let $f:\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ be the Ehrenfeucht-Mycielski sequence. The first few digits of the sequence are:
$$010011010111000100001111\ldots$$
For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ let $s(k) = \sum_{i=0}^k f(i)$. It is conjectured that $\lim_{n\to\infty} s(n)/n = 1/2$.
Question. Is it known that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} s(n)/n = \limsup_{n\to\infty} s(n)/n$?

OEIS has several entries related to the Ehrenfeucht-Mycielski sequence, see https://oeis.org/search?q=ehrenfeucht&language=english&go=Search – the main entry is https://oeis.org/A038219 which links to further work on the sequence. Perhaps some of the links give some information on the limit questions.

Quoting the Wikipedia page you have linked, with your notation: "it is known that every limit point of the sequence of values $s(n)/n$ lies between 1/4 and 3/4 inclusive."

Have you had a look at the links at the oeis page, Dominic?

Thanks Jerry - but I haven't found a hint as to whether the limit exists (aka lim inf equals lim sup)
